# .Net Frameworks Initialization Error

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2005

I have develop application on VS-2005 and installed it at another machine and along with application  I have installed .net frameworks 2.0 version as per demand and it works well at time of installed and  after some time if I try to open it it’s throw error like **“ .Net Framework Initialization Error,  Unable to find a version of the runtime to run this application."**

Client Machine : Operating System is XP sp2

How to overcome from it?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Above Problem Solved. There was virus infected PC so I have removed it first and Installed the fresh application again and now it is working very well.

Answer (score 0):

This error means your program cannot find or load mscorwks.dll.  Here are a few debugging steps:

- Make sure you have the correct version of the framework installed. Try repairing it in Add/Remove Programs.
- Check to see if your antivirus is causing issues. Try turning it off *temporarily* to see if that fixes the problem.
- If you have access to the source project, try creating a new application installer program in Visual Studio, uninstall the old application, and install the new application (which is the same application, just with a new installer).

Comment: @DarrellNorton, There is no antivirus installed on machine but it is always connected to online and i have tried to remove and installed .net frameworks 2.0.50727 but fail to do so.

Comment: On the new machine, is it also Visual Studio 2005, or is it 2008 or 2010?  The newer VS allows framework targeting, and it may have auto-upgraded your project.

Comment: @Darrell, There is not VS-2005, 2008 or 2010 installed.

Comment: Ah ok. So your deployed app can't find a .NET framework version. And you have checked to make sure it is installed in Add/Remove Programs. Try creating a new application installer from Visual Studio, uninstall the old program, and install the new one.

Comment: @Darrell, I have tried it by Add/Remove many times but fail to do so.

Comment: @mahesh: Did you try creating a new application installer from Visual Studio, uninstalling the old version, and installing the new one?